How to attach files in raw body in Postman?
I am trying to make a POST request with a file in a raw JSON body. I haven't found a clear-cut way to do this in Postman with raw body. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?
I know that I can use multipart/form-data, but that's not going to work with my requirements.

For JSON request and response, you can convert file to base64 for send file. Body of your request just like as bellow:
{
   "file" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
}

Consider, you should change your api for convert base64 to any file.
